# Django book tutorial chapter 8: fake capturing URL

Tags: django

Title of the section: [Faking Captured URLconf Values](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter08/)

(For expert: you can just skip to the bold part... the beginning is for learners like me)

From what I understand, the example given is nothing more than "url alias".

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^mydata/birthday/$', views.my_view, {'month': 'jan', 'day': '06'}),
    (r'^mydata/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d\d)/$', views.my_view),
)
```

So if we enter `http://example.com/mydata/May/18/`, I may this on the screen:

```
Hi C++ Learner, May 18 is your birthday!
```

With this URL techinque, I will see the same display if I enter `http://example.com/mydata/birthday`

**Notice month and day are hardcoded.** For a dynamic site today, how do we display the birthday page for each user using this technique (url-alias)?

In the view, we have to pass month and day to render_to_response in order for the template to use. But if I say the following this will throw error since month and day aren't defined in urls.py.

```
(r'^mydata/birthday/$', views.my_view, {'month': month, 'day': day})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a user profile model that contains the birthday information, require login before allowing access to that URL, and then pull the data from the profile in the view.

Comment: In this example, it only demonstrate a hard-code url alias. If I were implement this as profile feature, does the extra keyword help? Thanks.

Comment: Not in the urlconf. You could delegate to the original view in the new view after pulling the info from the profile though.